# Trying to select and output data from a list of Items but receiving this instead of the name I want

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, object, items

**System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator`2[ShopApp_Sem2_Project.Item,System.String]**

```
public class Item
{
    #region Properties

    public int ItemID { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public string Info { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }

    #endregion Properties

    #region Constructors
    public Item(int itemID, string product, string manufacturer, string category, double price, string info, string image)
    {
        ItemID = itemID;
        Manufacturer = manufacturer;
        Category = category;
        ProductName = product;
        Price = price;
        Info = info;
        Image = image;
    }
    #endregion Constructors
}
```

So this is my class with some properties and constructors which I'm using to create a shop. I populate a listbox called lbxCategories, but when trying to get any information after selecting from the listbox and using a linq statement I get that error seen above.

```
public partial class shopHome : Page
{
    string connectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\College Work\OOD\ShopApp_Sem2_Project\items.mdf;Integrated Security=True;";

    List<Item> allItems = new List<Item>();

    public shopHome()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void LbxCategories_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            string query = "SELECT * FROM items ORDER BY itemID";

            sqlCon.Open();

            SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlCon);

            SqlDataReader dr = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

            if(dr.HasRows)
            {
                while(dr.Read())
                {
                    Item newItem = new Item(Convert.ToInt32(dr[0]), dr[1].ToString(), dr[2].ToString(), dr[3].ToString(), Convert.ToDouble(dr[4]), dr[5].ToString(), dr[6].ToString());

                    allItems.Add(newItem);
                }

                if(allItems != null)
                {
                    var results = allItems.Select(x => x.Category).Distinct();

                    lbxCategories.ItemsSource = results;
                }
            }
            sqlCon.Close();
        }
    }

    private void LbxCategories_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        string selectedItem = lbxCategories.SelectedItem as string;

        var results = allItems.Select(x => x.ProductName).ToString();

        test.Text = results; // this is just to test and see if I can get any input which isn't gibberish

    }
```

So when I run the code everything goes smoothly until I click on an item in the listbox which gives me this

[In the middle I just stuck a textblock to output the ProductName to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qp1Z.png)

Any help is greatly appreciated as I have projects due in a few days and need to get this out of the way

Comment: Please explain what you expect `var results = allItems.Select(x => x.ProductName).ToString();` to **do**? It is doing what you asked, but it isn't clear what you **want** it to do...

Comment: Also please remove the `error` language from your question. People will think that an exception is being thrown (when it isn't). The results may be unexpected to you, but they aren't an error.

Comment: @mjwills Yeah sorry, I want it to output the name of the product which matches the category selected

Comment: `allItems.Select(x => x.ProductName).ToString();` It's list. If you want to join product names, use `string.join`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll be honest, it was a bit difficult to work out what you were trying to do with your code, but I think I have. Take a look at this:

```
private void LbxCategories_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.AddedItems != null && e.AddedItems.Count > 0)
    {
        string selected = (string)e.AddedItems[0];
        string productName = (from i in allItems where i.Category == selected select i.ProductName).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

This will give you the `ProductName` of the first `Item` which has the selected category. If you actually want *all* the products matching that category, then you can take off `FirstOrDefault` from the end and it will give you an `IEnumerable<String>` of all the matching product names.

Comment: This was it thank you so much. Sorry I'm new to Stack Overflow and the Software Industry in general so I'm not very good at explaining my problems but you got it anyways. Thanks again

Comment: Hey man so I've ran into a new problem. While this works for getting just the first value, I intend on having 4 or 5 `productNames` in each category. Not sure how to take this  `IEnumerable<string>` and put it into a list or the likes to be able to fill out 3 or 4 textblocks with product names

Comment: @LukeBrowne `IEnumerable<T>` is basically a (limited) "list". You can assign it to the `ItemsSource` of an `ItemsControl` (such as `ListBox`), just like you are doing with the categories.